# Automatically Coupon code stop working on front end Magneto 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, coupon, coupon-codes

I have used the coupon code before but now automatically Specific Coupon Code stop working on the website

It is generated properly but automatically it stops working

1: I have run all Setup upgrade and deploy command and reindex command after creating cart rule.

2: Tried Putting End date Date different variation But Still got no success

3: One thing I noticed that just red is coming to no text error message as you can see the screenshot[image: Error]

After checking Logs

> [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header'
>   element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the
>   latter doesn't exist [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken
>   reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child
>   to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'header-wrapper' element cannot be added as child to
>   'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] [] [2019-12-17
>   05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections'
>   element cannot be added as child to 'page.top', because the latter
>   doesn't exist [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference:
>   the 'top.container' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top',
>   because the latter doesn't exist [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03]
>   main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added
>   as child to 'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to
>   'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
>   [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header' tries
>   to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different:
>   'header.container' and '' respectively. [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03]
>   main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' tries to
>   reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different:
>   'header.container' and '' respectively. [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03]
>   main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'navigation.sections' tries to
>   reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.top'
>   and '' respectively. [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken
>   reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but
>   their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header'
>   respectively. [] [] [2019-12-17 05:43:03] main.INFO: Broken reference:
>   the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but
>   their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively.
>   [] []  main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder
>   itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different:
>   'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []

Comment: Is there any exception in M2 Log file?

Comment: Check log and reindex data.

Comment: What Magento Version are you using? 
Check if there is an error_log file(if yes then check its contents) also look out for exception.log entries. 
You could also check the Ajax Request Sent in the Browser console when you click Apply Discount Button.

Comment: i m using 2.3.1 after checking exception.log file                                    [2019-12-16 23:55:42] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: data in /home/niddhi/public_html/app/code/MGS/Social/Block/Panel/Widget.php on line 333 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: data in /home/niddhi/public_html/app/code/MGS/Social/Block/Panel/Widget.php on line 333 at /home/niddhi/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the hosting server they disable PUT and DELETE Method after enabling these two Method the coupons started working correctly. so my advice if your facing same kindly first contact your hosting and then try to troubleshoot problem it will save your time